# Cannot add a route with the same class and method as an existing route

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am trying to addRoutes but getting *"Cannot add a route with the same class and method as an existing route."*

I have a class Thing that has the same route method for Post, but with a different method of course. When I try to run my app I get the above error. Is there a way to setup the route with a generic method?

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Thing class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/things/update_location.json.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];

[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Thing class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/things.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

The above is a duplicate according to Restkit, as it using the same class "Thing" and because the Method is the same?  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A router is used to build a request when given an object (an instance of `Thing` in this case). For this to work there can only be a single option of what to do when you ask RestKit to post an object. Any other routes need to be described in terms of named routes or relationship routes to maintain the uniqueness of the routing set.

You can check the documentation [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKRouter.html) and it describes all 3 of the methods for defining routers in the 'Route Generation' section (you're currently only using method 2). Most likely you want to define some named routes which describe the differences between what you are trying to achieve with each upload.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what the last sentence means. Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone with the code, heres how to set up the route with name.

```
// When you are setting up your mapping, set up Route with Name.
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:LOGIN_URL
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:LOGIN_ROUTE pathPattern:LOGIN_URL method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


// And when you are ready to make the http call, do the following
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:LOGIN_ROUTE
                                                        object:userProfile
                                                    parameters:params
                                                       success:success
                                                       failure:failure];
```